# PHP/Ajax load more button

Tags: php, ajax

I want to display 5 items and when the user clicks the 'load more' button, 5 more items will be pulled out from the database.

I have my items being retrieved like so:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
```

then i have the ajax code and the button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".load_more").click(function (){
            $('.load_more').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.ajax({
                url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + ("<?php echo $id; ?>"),
                success: function(html){
                    if(html){
                        $(".main_page").append(html);
                        $('.load_more').html('Load More');
                    }else{
                        $('.load_more').replaceWith('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>



    <button class="load_more">Load More</button>
```

And finally the loadmore.php file that is being called when the button is clicked:

```
    $res17 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE id < '".addslashes($_GET['lastid'])."' LIMIT 0, 25 LIMIT 10"); 
while($row17 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res17)){
            $id = $row17['id'];
            $user_id = $row17['user_id'];
```

how do i call the correct id? i know that
  url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + (""), is probably wrong but not sure how to fix it

Comment: What you can try is adding the `id's`of each item into a `data` attribute, then use jQuery to find the last item, get the `id` of that last item, then send the appropriate request.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `LIMIT 0, 25 LIMIT 10` syntax in your query...are you sure it's valid? My first instinct would be to pass a "page" (which, in your case is really the number of times you've clicked the Load More button), and then use `$limit = 5; $offset = $_GET['page'] * $limit; $query = '... LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset';`

Comment: @KevinPei i tired adding <div class="post_display" id="'. $id .'"> for  the while loop with the posts and for the ajax i added  url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".post_display:last").attr("id"), still does not work. i get an error " mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource"

Comment: got rid of the error with while($res17 && $row17 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res17)){ but when clicking load more, i get "no more posts" but i do have more posts so that does not make sense

Comment: any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was the issue but you forgot to close some of the opening curly brackets,
I have fixed it here.

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
}}
```